# Jump past special character once 2 characters entered VBA userform

Tags: vba, excel

Not sure if it is possible but is there a piece of code that states when you enter 2 characters then it jumps past the : or / symbol (one for date & one for time that needs manually entering.

I'm guessing it needs to be in the change event of the textbox but not sure on the type of code for setting focus to 3 digits in once 2 have been entered.

Thanks
Al

Comment: enter 2 characters where? what characters? I am not sure I understand your question. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I get the impression you're trying to create an input mask-like effect, is that correct?

Comment: Basically I want to enter the date in one field once i enter 01022014 it will jump after the first 2 characters past / and then again 2 characters to jump past another / to then show like this 01/02/2014 and then again with time so if I type 1159 after the first 2 characters it will show 11:59 @vba4all

Comment: @aiken unfortunately I have no experience of mask like effects so I hope the above explanation will make it a bit clearer

Comment: @AlanTreanor Ok, are we talking a TextBox control on a UserForm now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a sample UserForm1 with 2 TextBoxes (`TextBox1` for the date, `TextBox2` for the time)

[image]

You can constantly check the length of the string typed in the textboxes and if it is equal to 8 for the date or 4 for the time you manipulate the value ie.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim current As String
    current = TextBox1.Value

    If Len(TextBox1) = 8 Then
        current = Left(TextBox1, 2) & "/" & Mid(TextBox1, 3, 2) & "/" & Right(TextBox1, 4)
        TextBox1 = current
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    Dim current As String
    current = TextBox2.Value

    If Len(TextBox2) = 4 Then
        current = Left(TextBox2, 2) & ":" & Right(TextBox2, 2)
        TextBox2 = current
    End If
End Sub
```

so now if you start the UserForm1 and type for example `10102014` the code will automatically convert it to a date format adding the forward slashes in between the characters. Same goes for the time

[image]